# flutter issues using repository on page

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: img]

The named parameter 'subtitle' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'subtitle'.

also

The named parameter 'onTap' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onTap'

Comment: if you try to build this project, will it be successful?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `)` in the end of `title` properties.

So your code should be like:

```
title: new Text(subs[index]),
subtitle: new Text(subs[index]),
onTap: (){ //Your Code },
```